# Rendering multiple buttons with onClick function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to render multiple buttons in react using map but i am getting an errors.

```js
var NameArray = [{"name":"number0"},{"name":"number1"},{"name":"number2"}];

class RenderButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const {id} = event.target;
    console.log(id);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {NameArray.map((obj, index) =>
        <h3 id={index} onClick={this.onClick}>
          {obj.name}
        </h3>
      )}
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<RenderButtons />, 
document.querySelector('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I am using index as Id for my buttons and NameArray properties as name of the buttons.

I tried spliting render of buttons to new function but i am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you miss `#` sign in your `querySelector` function.

```
document.querySelector('#app');
```

Comment: I am doing this for too long <.<.